# change class name in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

am making a site, I have menu as components in ascx.

I want to change my class name to different name;

this is my code:

```
<div id="mainMenu" style="float: left;">
    <ul class="level1 static">
        <li class="menu" style="position: relative;">test </li>
        <li class="menu" style="position: relative;">test </li>
        <li class="menu" style="position: relative;">test </li>
        <li class="menu" style="position: relative;">test </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

for one of the page, I want to add my own style to the menu li.
so I want all classes changed to:

```
class="apple" 
class="grape" 
class="bannana"
class="orange"
```

how will I do this in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // ?
</script>
```

Comment: How will you determine which `li` should have which class?

Comment: you need to distinguish between your li first. as in give them different classnames or ids.

Comment: cant i rename the class using jquery

Comment: @al123 do you know removeClass, addClass?

Comment: @al123 ofcourse you can with $("menu").removeClass("menu").addClass("orange"); but you need unique id/class otherwise it will do it for all classes.

Comment: Too many `n`s in banana :)

Comment: If this is an ascx, why aren't you changing the classes where the menu is generated (server-side)? This seems a really bad thing to do client-side as it is hard-wired to depend on the content and order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the entire className attributes you can use the `attr` method and if you want to add classes you can use the `addClass` method. Both methods accept callback function which is executed for each selected element, you can use an array and the first parameter of the callbacks for modifying the `class` attributes:

```
var cls = ["apple", "grape", "bannana", "orange"];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainMenu .level1 > li').addClass(function(i) {
        return cls[i];
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Works, but the whole situation seems contrived. Why does nobody stop to question *why this is not done server-side*? :)

Comment: is there a reason why it doesnt take affect, when i inspect element it still shows as menu for all classes, even though in page souce it shows the fuction

Comment: @al123 wrap the whole thing inside $(function() { });

Comment: No, the problem is that he is looking for .remove class first and add the new class see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/8bYaG/

Comment: its still not updating, iv put it in a script aswell

Comment: @al123 What do you mean by "in aspx page"? I'm not ASP developer, so I don't know how scripts are loaded by that framework, but generally JavaScript code are executed by browser's JS interpreter, so that doesn't change anything. It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/5fepC/, you should do some basic debugging in your page which is beyond the scope of this question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass("orange");
    $("ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass("apple");
    $("ul li:nth-child(3)").addClass("foo");
    $("ul li:nth-child(4)").addClass("bar");
})
```

Comment: Works, but the whole situation seems contrived. Why does nobody stop to question *why this is not done server-side*? :)

Comment: good point :) but I think it's too obvious to be as simple as that :D

Comment: how do i add this on aspx

Comment: put it in a script tag

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate on your li's and will add whatever they have as visible text value as a class in lowercase, like this you don't have to worry about the order and you can control it from your markup.

```
<li class="menu">Apple</li>
<li class="menu">Orange</li>


$('.level1 li').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});
```

If you want to remove the menu class first you can simply chain it in the above command, like that.

`$(this).removeClass('menu').addClass($(this).text().toLowerCase());`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class using .addClass and .removeClass:

```
// remove class
$("li").removeClass("menu")

// add clasd
$("li").addClass("orange");
```

jQuery API:

- http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/
- http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: but now how will i add apple

Comment: $("li").addClass("apple"); - are you trying to keep some sort of ordering with the above? Your question just listed classes.

Comment: at the moment my classes are all menu, but i need to change them all to different names. if i remove menu, and add orange then they all will be orange but i dont want them all to be orange

Comment: Do they need to maintain a specific order? If so, IIvanov's answer above retains the order they're in. If you're going to dynamically change them we'll need to know more about how/when they should be changed.

Comment: You can chain them and make it look like this `$('li').removeClass("menu").addClass("orange");`

Comment: how do i add this in aspx